# Assets not loading inside applet's jar file

Tags: java, jar, applet, assets

I have an jar file with an applet. This applet runs perfectly except for one thing: when I run the applet the program loads but the images don't. I know that is the only error. The manifest file inside the jar specifies another jar I use inside that, and I know it is imported correctly. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the images ?

-> If deployed in the jar, you need to access them from the classpath as a resource.

Something like,

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/resources/image.jpg");
Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
```

Applets typically have limitations, they can only connect to the server that served them.

Comment: they are inside the jar. Also, do you add the packages to the class path or the images one by one?

Comment: I don't understand your question. the applet itself is part of the CP, there is nothing todo. inside the jar in a folder called /resources, dump your images

Comment: it is, but for some reason, the applet doesn't show the images

Comment: are you using the code above, how do you reference the image, how do you read it. We need extra skills to read through your eyes...

Comment: *"do you add the packages to the class path or the images one by one?"*  If all the classes and images are in the same Jar, they can be added to the run-time class-path of the applet by adding a reference to the Jar in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element. @OlivierRefalo *"We need extra skills to read through your eyes..."*  That or being psychic.  ;)